# Send an Email when no inserts occur for a specified time period in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, email

One of the computers in my department runs an excel macro every 30 seconds.  When it finishes, it submits a row to a table in a SQL Server DB that I control (I don't have the ability to change the macro).

I would like to demonstrate how frequently this setup fails by sending an email when there have been no new records during a given period.  I'm familiar with sending emails through SQL Server but I don't know how to accomplish the timing.

How do I trigger an email when there is no activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a job that would run every half an hour and select the most recent row from the table based on the Id or date, and send the email with the result. If there is no new row you can conclude the outcome.

Comment: Thanks...  used to working with triggers but not with schedueled jobs.  A search has filled in the rest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a job that runs periodically - every minute, five minutes, etc. - and have it check the date/time of the last inserted record.  If it's been greater than a predefined amount of time, you fire an email off.

Comment: Thanks...  used to working with triggers but not with schedueled jobs.  A search has filled in the rest.  Thanks!